# How to install two versions of the same app so Android wont install it as an update

Tags: applications, installation, apk, editing

I have a game called [mindustry](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.anuke.mindustry&hl=en_US) on my phone, and want to use the `.apk` for the current version separately from the beta version. What would I need to do to make my device not install the newer `.apk` as an update?

Sorry if my question is unclear. If you need clarification I will do my best to provide it, this is just a weird problem and I could not think how to ask it.

EDIT: repackaging the app worked, app functions normally, only had to change the app package and nothing else

Comment: What you want to to is called app repackaging. Android identifies apps based on the packagename in the androidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Uh, there are other ways that are on-topic here (repackaging is developer stuff and thus off-topic here). Maybe better rephrase along the lines of "how to use two versions of the same app in parallel". There are some ways, I remember (but not enough to answer).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will see if this works.